# How to get the checked checkboxes values with ID in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I'm currently trying to get the values of checked checkboxes. These checkboxes have unique IDs because they are defined on a modal box.

```
<input type = 'checkbox' id = 'audience_Name-$row[asset_ID]' value = 'SMB'> SMB
<input type = 'checkbox' id = 'audience_Name-$row[asset_ID]' value = 'SMB'> SMB
<input type = 'checkbox' id = 'audience_Name-$row[asset_ID]' value = 'SMB'> SMB
<input type = 'checkbox' id = 'audience_Name-$row[asset_ID]' value = 'SMB'> SMB
<input type = 'checkbox' id = 'audience_Name-$row[asset_ID]' value = 'SMB'> SMB
<input type = 'button' id = 'editAssetColumn' value = 'Submit'>
```

And here, I'm testing if I'm retrieving them but unfortunately, I cannot.

```
$("button#editAssetColumn").click( function() {
    var edit_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var name = $("input#audience_Name:checked-"+edit_id).val();
    $('input#audience_Name:checked-'+edit_id).each(function() {
        alert("Success!");
    }); 
});
```

I believe it's the syntax... Thanks in advance!

Comment: protip: `this.id` > `$(this).attr("id");`. Also, don't use `alert()` as a debugging tool. `console.log()` is made just for that.

Comment: Hmm okay thanks for the suggestion. But my problem right now is syntax. I'm not really sure if I'm retrieving all the checked checkboxes with these codes. Specifically this line: "$('input#audience_Name:checked-'+edit_id).each(function() {". Am I getting all the checked checkboxes which are defined with an ID?

Comment: Cant get some logics #1 alert(audience_Name) where is 'audience_Name' defined. #2 $("input#audience_Name:checked-"+edit_id) does not make sense

Comment: Sorry, don't mind it. It's a string now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is html and js, there were multiple problems in your code, [JSFIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/mm2ntuj4/1/)

**HTML**

```
<input type = 'checkbox' id = 'audience_Name[]-$row[1]' class="audience_Name" value = 'SMB'> SMB
<input type = 'checkbox' id = 'audience_Name[]-$row[2]' class="audience_Name" value = 'SMB'> SMB
<input type = 'checkbox' id = 'audience_Name[]-$row[3]' class="audience_Name" value = 'SMB'> SMB
<input type = 'checkbox' id = 'audience_Name[]-$row[4]' class="audience_Name"  value = 'SMB'> SMB
<input type = 'checkbox' id = 'audience_Name[]-$row[5]'  class="audience_Name"  value = 'SMB'> SMB
<input type = 'button' id = 'editAssetColumn' value = 'Submit'>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#editAssetColumn").click( function() {
    console.log("here");
    $('.audience_Name:checked').each(function() {
        console.log("asdfsf");
    }); 
  });
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/km2vLfvz/ I added a `this.id` instead of asdfsf. But this is probably what he is after.

Answer (score 0):

Your `id` is in the wrong format. it should be `"input#audience_Name-" + edit_id + ":checked"`. since you are using the jQuery `:checked` selector.

Comment: In terms of syntax, this is what I'm looking for. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I'm using console.log() because I'm not a fan of getting a bazillion popups… But other than that, it's the same thing.

```
$("#editAssetColumn").on("click", function() {
  $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```